# Flask: Connect to sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask

So I'm new to Python and I'm currently experimenting with Flask. I've read numerous docs and blogs on how to just configure the connection to a simple database using flask but without any success. Can you guys help me?

I don't want anything fancy right now, just to get a connection working. Below is the code right now with a simple test-query that I want to get working.

The result of this is an ordinary 500 Internal Server Error.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

from flask import Flask
import sqlite3
from flask import g

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")


@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db.close()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    g.db.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES 'TestValue'")
    g.db.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: A 500 error would result in a traceback on the console, can you share that? Does your `database.db` database actually *have* a `test` table in it? You are also using a relative path, so `database.db` will be opened in the current working directory. This may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: You are not actually returning any data from your view function - what happens if you - 1. add `return 'Hello World'` after your `g.db.commit()` and 2. change `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things that may be causing a problem here:

First, your application needs to import the Flask class before it can construct the app. So:

> `app = Flask(__name__):`

Should **follow** the import statements.

I'm assuming that since you got a 500 server error that this isn't causing the problem.

Second, there's a small syntax error in your insertion. It should read:

`g.db.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('TestValue')")`

Please read the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) on the correct syntax for using insertions. Or see [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_insert_query.htm) (which is actually a bit more englightening).

Finally, I **suspect** that you have no database set up yet which is why there is an insertion error. E.g., how can Flask insert data into the table if the database doesn't exist?

You should recognize that Flask **is** smart enough to create a SQLite database which you will find in the working directory named `database.db` Which is exactly what you did here:

> `g.db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")`

But that isn't going to populate that database with the correct schema to allow you to actually insert data through the Flask application. What you need is to initialize the database by writing the schema to the database. For example, create the schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
    field1 STRING
);
```

Then, at the command prompt issue:

`sqlite3 database.db < schema.sql`

That will create a database with a single table called test, which accepts a single field of type string. Now that the database is initialized you can write to it via your Flask application. Larger projects will usually have a database initialization script.